# Google Plus API is Deprecated. How do i get gender and birth date from requestScopes(Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))

Tags: android, kotlin, google-signin

Google Plus API is Deprecated. How do i get gender and birth date from request Scope. Below is my code:

```
val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken("xxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com")
                .requestEmail()
                .requestProfile()
                .requestScopes(Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
                .build()

   val mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)
```

From this sign in option i want gender and birth date of google user.

```
 public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            val result = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            try {
                val account = result.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                //Here I want gender and date of birth from google sign in option
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

        }
    }
```